# How to get count in HashMap having correspondence?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have this problem where I need something to match an area_code with a phone number, and at the end I need the count of phoneNumbers in each area_code, I think i can use a Map. Do you have any ideas?

```
Example

Given area_code: 351 phone_number:123456
Given area_code: 351 phone_number:1234567
Given area_code: 111 phone_number:678904

Output
351:2 (2 is the count on the numbers)
111:1 (1 is the count on the numbers)
```

Comment: Do you need to keep the phone numbers stored as well?

Comment: No I just need the area_code and the count @JacobWood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Map to store the counts for each area_code:

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> areaCodes = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

public void addAreaCode(String areaCode) {
    if (areaCodes.containsKey(areaCode)) {
        areaCodes.put(areaCode, areaCodes.get(areaCode) + 1);
    } else {
        areaCodes.put(areaCode, 1);
    }
}

public void foo() {
    addAreaCode("351");
    addAreaCode("351");
    addAreaCode("111");

    for (String areaCode : areaCodes.keySet()) {
        System.out.printf("%s:%d\n", areaCode, areaCodes.get(areaCode));
    }
}
```

I used Strings to store the area_codes in case any begin with `0`.

Comment: Let me try it out

Comment: Your "hasKey" does not exist Jacob

Comment: @Jose Sorry, it should be `containsKey`.

Comment: Ok it works, just tell me how to eliminate duplicates, for example it appears me 
351:1
351:2

Comment: The keys are being accessed as a set so naturally there should be no duplicates. Perhaps they're being entered with special characters appended/prepended? (i.e. spaces, newlines, etc.)

Comment: it would be better to iterate over the `entrySet`  and directly access the key and value for each entry rather than iterating over the `keySet` and then doing a lookup in the map for every key.

Comment: @Aominè Fair, but I mostly just wanted to demonstrate how to store the data in a Map.

Answer (score 4):

First, create a class with two fields, one to represent the area code (`String`), and another to represent the phone number (`String`). Once that is complete you can then spin up however many objects required; populating it with the necessary data and then store this into a List.

once that is done you can then use a [`groupingBy`](http://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector) collector to count the number of phone numbers belonging to each group (area code) like this:

```
Map<String, Long> resultSet = 
       myList.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ClassName::getAreaCode, Collectors.counting()));
```

or if you just want to print then you can do:

```
myList.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ClassName::getAreaCode, Collectors.counting()))
      .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(String.join(":", k, v.toString())));
```

Comment: How can I pass the phone numbers and area_codes to that?

Comment: @Jose what do you mean?

Comment: Probably best to use Strings in case the area_codes / phone_numbers start with `0`.

Comment: If you use a map, you can have at most one phone number per area code, so you could never model the OP's question where you have multiple phone numbers in one area code, and OP wants to count how many in each.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt good point, don't know what I was thinking at the time I wrote this answer. updated. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a `Phone` class as follows:

```
public class Phone {
    private final String areaCode;
    private final String number;

    public Phone(String areaCode, String number) {
        this.areaCode = areaCode;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getAreaCode() { return areaCode; }

    public String getNumber() { return number; }
}
```

Then, once you have a list of phones, such as this one:

```
List<Phone> phoneNumbers = Arrays.asList(
    new Phone("351", "123456"),
    new Phone("351", "1234567"),
    new Phone("111", "678904"));
```

You could use either streams (such as in [Aominè's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48236009/1876620)) or the [`Map.merge` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-), this way:

```
Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
phoneNumbers.forEach(phone -> result.merge(phone.getAreaCode(), 1, Integer::sum));
```

This iterates the phone numbers list, and for each one of them, it puts an entry in the `result` map, with the area code being the key and `1` being the value. If, for the current phone number, the map already contained an entry with the its area code, then, `1` is added to the value of that entry via the `Integer::sum` merger function.

Comment: nice solution. I keep forgetting that a lot of things can be achieved in Java-8 without the use of streams but for some reason, I am always taking the streams route. +1.

Comment: Also, it's a wise option to use `String` for the phone numbers like you've done as some numbers may start with `0` in which case using integer wouldn't be a good option for it.

Comment: @Aominè Thanks, I always answer with merge and computeifabsent to show an alternative way to streams. But this doesn't mean that streams are bad or incorrect. It's just another way... Actually I have upvoted your answer

Comment: @Aominè re phone numbers, I always use strings, not only because of the possible 0 at the beginning, but also because many times + and - symbols are used.